# .ko file isn't produced after the make command

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to compile a simple hello world kernel module but after the make command, I'm receiving the warnings below and moduleName.ko file isn't produced. What is the reason for the problem? Do the warnings block to be produced .ko file? How can I solve this? Thanks.

The output after the make command:

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.20.15-custom/build SUBDIRS= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.20.15'
CHK     include/linux/version.h
CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1595 modules
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.data:boot_params from .text be tween '_text' (at offset 0xc0100036) and 'startup_32_smp'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.data:boot_params from .text between '_text' (at offset 0xc0100044) and 'startup_32_smp'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.data:init_pg_tables_end from .text between '_text' (at offset 0xc01000a6) and 'startup_32_smp'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:start_kernel from .text between 'is386' (at offset 0xc0100221) and 'check_x87'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:smp_prepare_cpus from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc0100438) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:migration_init from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc010043d) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:spawn_ksoftirqd from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc0100442) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:spawn_softlockup_task from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc0100447) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:smp_cpus_done from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc01004bf) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:sched_init_smp from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc01004c4) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:cpuset_init_smp from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc01004c9) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:usermodehelper_init from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc01004d6) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:driver_init from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc01004db) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:sysctl_init from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc01004e1) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.data: from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc0100507) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.data: from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc0100524) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:prepare_namespace from .text between 'init' (at offset 0xc010070f) and 'rest_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:__alloc_bootmem from .text between 'init_gdt' (at offset 0xc010a1fb) and 'cpu_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:__alloc_bootmem from .text between 'init_gdt' (at offset 0xc010a211) and 'cpu_init'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:sysenter_setup from .text between 'identify_cpu' (at offset 0xc010a8de) and 'display_cacheinfo'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:mtrr_bp_init from .text between 'identify_cpu' (at offset 0xc010a8e8) and 'display_cacheinfo'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:trap_init_f00f_bug from .text between 'init_intel' (at offset 0xc010c7f5) and 'cpuid4_cache_lookup'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.data:initkmem_list3 from .text between 'set_up_list3s' (at offset 0xc0170e0f) and 's_start'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:eisa_root_register from .text between 'pci_eisa_init' (at offset 0xc0263ebb) and 'virtual_eisa_release'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:eisa_root_register from .text between 'virtual_eisa_root_init' (at offset 0xc0263f1f) and 'cpufreq_unregister_driver'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text: from .text between 'iret_exc' (at offset 0xc02e8dbb) and '_etext'
WARNING: vmlinux - Section mismatch: reference to .init.text:start_kernel from .paravirtprobe between '__start_paravirtprobe' (at offset 0xc03b34b0) and '__stop_paravirtprobe'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.20.15'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think variable *M* is missing in your command - it should point to path the source code of module resides:

```
make -C path-to-linux-src M=path-to-module-src modules
```

Comment: I use SUBDIRS instead of M. I tried with M but I got the same result with M instead of SUBDIRS in the output.

Comment: @stedkka In your output you didn't assigned value to SUBDIR - it should be SUBDIR=path-to-your-module-src

Comment: In Makefile, there is a `SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules` line.

Comment: @stedkka Try SUBDIRS=$(shell pwd) and see in output if SUBDIR has a value.

Comment: @dimbaThis works fine.  Moreover , jørgensen's answer also works. Today, I wasted hours to fix this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use `make -C /lib/modules/2.6.20.15-custom/build M=$$PWD` (`$$PWD`, and no need for `modules` either).

Comment: `$$PWD` should also be faster since you don't have to spawn an extra shell just to call `pwd`. `$(PWD)` on the other hand is not going to work because I doubt you have defined such in your makefile. Other than that: 1. don't rely on environment variables (because a shell might withhold them on purpose), 2. don't contain what you would expect.